# 2 Tables ScanHospitals and Scanpricelist not getting added in Magento 1.9...I need correct code to add these tables

Tags: magento-1.9, database

```
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$installer->run("
-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->getTable('scanpricelist')};
CREATE TABLE {$this->getTable('scanpricelist')} (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
'city' varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
'scan' varchar(150) NOT NULL default '',
'scan_type' varchar(250) not NULL default '',
'hospital' varchar(250) not NULL default '',
'hospital_price' int(50) not NULL default '',
'bms_price' int(50) not NULL default '',
'consultation_charge' int(50) not NULL default '',
'additional_charge' int(50) not NULL default '',
PRIMARY KEY ('id')
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
");
```